# Select current and previous line if values are the same in 2 columns

Tags: awk

Check values in columns 2 and 3, if the values are the same in the previous line and current line( example lines 2-3 and 6-7), then print the lines separated as ,

**Input file**

```
1   1   2 35  1
2   3   4 50  1
2   3   4 75  1
4   7   7 85  1
5   8   6 100 1
8   6   9 125 1
4   6   9 200 1
5   3   2 156 2
```

**Desired output**

```
2,3,4,50,1,2,3,4,75,1
8,6,9,125,1,4,6,9,200,1
```

I tried to modify this code, but not results

```
awk '{$6=$2 $3 - $p2 $p3} $6==0{print p0; print} {p0=$0;p2=p2;p3=$3}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; cK=$2 FS $3} pK==cK{print p0, $0} {pK=cK; p0=$0}' file
2,3,4,50,1,2,3,4,75,1
8,6,9,125,1,4,6,9,200,1
```

Comment: Why `FS` in `$2 FS $3` ? Since it's only for compare, isn't the `FS` superfluous?

Comment: @Tiw a separator is necessary because `a bc` and `ab c` both concatenate to `abc` if you don't include one.

Answer (score 1):

With your own code and its mechanism updated:

```
awk '(($2=$2) $3) - (p2 p3)==0{printf "%s", p0; print} {p0=$0;p2=$2;p3=$3}' OFS="," file
2,3,4,50,12,3,4,75,1
8,6,9,125,14,6,9,200,1
```

But it has underlying problem, so better use this simplified/improved way:

```
awk '($2=$2) FS $3==cp{print p0,$0} {p0=$0; cp=$2 FS $3}' OFS=, file
```

The `FS` is needed, check the comments under [Mr. Morton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54736368/5403468).

Why your code fails:

- Concatenate (what space do) has higher priority than minus`-`.
- You used `$6` to save the value you want to compare, and then it becomes a part of `$0` the line.(last column). -- You can change it to a temporary variable name.
- You have a typo (`p2=p2`), and you used `$p2` and `$p3`, which means to get `p2`'s value and find the corresponding column. So if `p2==3` then `$p2` equals `$3`.
- You didn't set `OFS`, so even if your code works, the output will be separated by  spaces.
- `print` will add a trailing newline`\n`, so even if above problems don't exist, you will get 4 lines instead of the 2 lines output you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk 'prev_2nd==$2 && prev_3rd==$3{$1=$1;print prev_line,$0} {prev_2nd=$2;prev_3rd=$3;$1=$1;prev_line=$0}' OFS=,  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '
prev_2nd==$2 && prev_3rd==$3{     ##Checking if previous lines variable prev_2nd and prev_3rd are having same value as current line 2nd and 3rd field or not, if yes then do following.
  $1=$1                           ##Resetting $1 value of current line to $1 only why because OP needs output field separator as comma and to apply this we need to reset it to its own value.
  print prev_line,$0              ##Printing value of previous line and current line here.
}                                 ##Closing this condition block here.
{
  prev_2nd=$2                     ##Setting current line $2 to prev_2nd variable here.
  prev_3rd=$3                     ##Setting current line $3 to prev_3rd variable here.
  $1=$1                           ##Resetting value of $1 to $1 to make comma in its values applied.
  prev_line=$0                    ##Now setting pre_line value to current line edited one with comma as separator.
}
' OFS=,  Input_file               ##Setting OFS(output field separator) value as comma here and mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @OXXO, could you please check this once, if this helped you too?